# Can I make a custom Delphi component add multiple units to the uses clause?

Tags: delphi, components

I'm working on some components in XE2. Is it possible to have more than the component's unit added to the uses clause of the form it's dropped on?

Example:
When I choose the TCustomComponent from a package I've built and installed the unit CustomComponent is added to the form's uses clause. I would like to also add the unit GlobalConstants.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a design-time package for your component (if you do not already have one).  In that package, create a class that implements the [`ISelectionEditor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/DesignIntf.ISelectionEditor) interface (the easiest way is to derive from the [`TSelectionEditor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/DesignEditors.TSelectionEditor) class), overriding its virtual [`RequiresUnits()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/DesignIntf.ISelectionEditor.RequiresUnits) method to report any additional units you want to appear in the `uses` clause of any Form/Frame/DataModule that uses your component.  Then, have your package's `Register()` function register that class by calling [`RegisterSelectionEditor()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/DesignIntf.RegisterSelectionEditor) (in addition to [`RegisterComponents()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Classes.RegisterComponents)).

[Indy 10](http://www.indyproject.org) does exactly this for its `TIdTCPServer`, `TIdCmdTCPClient`, and `TIdUDPServer` components, to make sure the `IdContext` and `IdSocketHandle` units get added to `uses` clauses.  Look at the `IdCoreSelectionEditors.pas` and `IdRegisterCore.pas` units to see how Indy implements this.

**Update**: the `IdCoreSelectionEditors.pas` and `IdProtocolsSelectionEditors.pas` units were removed from Indy 10 in March 2014.  All of the per-component SelectionEditor classes were replaced with a new single class implemented in the `IdRegisterCore` unit itself.  This new SelectionEditor class is registered for all Indy components, and it looks for all instances of any Indy component that has been placed at design-time, using RTTI of the data types of all parameters and return values for any assigned event handlers to know which units to report for inclusion in the `uses` clause.