# How do I build a custom non-visual component for TMS WEB Core?

Tags: delphi, custom-component, tms, tms-web-core, delphi-12-athens

I tried following [this](https://download.tmssoftware.com/doc/tmswebcore/gettingstarted/customcontroldevelopment/) document about how to build a non-visual component for TMS WEB Core, but it's not working.

This is my full unit code:

```
unit MyTestCustomComponents;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, WebLib.Controls;

type
  [ComponentPlatforms(TMSWebPlatform)]
  TMyWebComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  published
    { Published declarations }
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('My Web Test Components', [TMyWebComponent]);
end;

end.
```

I'm able to successfully compile my .bpl package file and install it into my Delphi IDE. I'm also then able to find the component in my component palette and place it onto my form.

But as soon as I compile my web app with my custom component on it, then I get an error in my component unit:

> [Error] MyTestCustomComponents.pas(9): identifier not found "TMSWebPlatform"

It's not finding `TMSWebPlatform`. I have `WebLib.Controls` on my uses just like the [document](https://download.tmssoftware.com/doc/tmswebcore/gettingstarted/customcontroldevelopment/) explains and I have the attribute `[ComponentPlatforms(TMSWebPlatform)]` in there.

What am I doing wrong? Why is my custom non-visual component not working and finding `TMSWebPlatform`?

Comment: Start with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332203/can-i-make-a-custom-delphi-component-add-multiple-units-to-the-uses-clause to add required units to projects the component is used in.

Comment: Looking at the TMS source, TMS includes an {IFNDEF LCLTMSWEB} before [ComponentPlatforms(TMSWebPlatform)] .. you asked a similar question, and the prevailing comment was that it's used for Lazarus..